# Why aren't bubble helmets dangerous in direct sunlight?

Tags: spacesuits, safety, sunlight

I've been thinking lately about bubble helmets used by many cosmonauts and astronauts. Almost every space suit I've seen features **a curved helmet**, even the Gemini astronauts.

But a curved piece of glass/plastic **should focus sunlight** somewhere beyond the convex side, maybe with a little spherical aberration, but potentially still dangerous. We all know what a magnifying glass does when held at the right distance in open sunlight.

Now obviously, no space traveler has suffered this terrible fate, so I will phrase the question these ways: Why doesn't focused heat happen through the curved visors of spacesuit? Why aren't bubble helmets dangerous in direct sunlight?

Comment: I imagine the focus of the sunlight passing through the curvature is substantially behind the person's face.

Comment: There is no focussing for light passing through a curved piece of glass, unless the front and back surfaces have *different* radii of curvature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A curved piece of glass/plastic should focus sunlight somewhere beyond the convex side

This is true;  however it requires that the curvature of the two sides of the piece of glass be ***different***

When the Lens Maker's Formula 
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/geoopt/lenmak.html is applied to acurved piece of glass with the two identical radii of curvature, the focal length is infinite...

This image

[image]

shows the various categories of converging or diverging lenses, based on the radius of curvature of the two surfaces.  Note that a lens with the two surfaces curved ***and*** parallel is notable missing...

Curved surface ***mirrors*** are of course a different matter.  This hotel http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1315978/Las-Vegas-hotel-death-ray-leaves-guests-severe-burns.html found out the danger of a south facing curved glass wall...

Comment: I see, but keep in mind that a spherical helmet will have different radii, if the thickness is kept constant. The inside radius will be slightly shorter than the outside radius. I plugged in 20 and 21 cm into that formula you linked to and got a focal length of 8.4 m, so it seems the astronaut's head is safe.